# OpenSSL WARNINGS when using -purpose command

Tags: openssl

I created a self-signed certificate with OpenSSL.
When using the -purpose parameter to examine the certificate I see some warnings in the output.

Can someone explain this warnings ?

> C:\OpenSSL\keys>C:\OpenSSL\bin\openssl x509 -in ca.crt -purpose
>
> Certificate purposes:
> SSL client : Yes
> SSL client CA : Yes (WARNING code=3)
> SSL server : Yes
> SSL server CA : Yes (WARNING code=3)

Comment: is the warning due to the fact that the cert is not from a trusted root CA?